# Ping remote computer from another remote computer and get result back

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file

I'm trying to get a batch script to work whereby I get computer A on which my script is running to get computer B to ping computer C and get back an errorlevel that I can output.
At the moment i'm trying to do this by using PSEXEC to access command line on computer B and getting it to ping C. the issue of course is that the errorlevel always comes back as "0" since the command is successfully executing on B. but it is the result from C that I need.

```
SET /P ALTTERM=Please specify another terminal to test from [0**]?
ECHO.
ECHO Running internal ping test from terminal %ALTTERM%...
PSEXEC \\%HOSTNAME%-%ALTTERM% PING %HOSTNAME%-%TERMINAL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 SET INTERNALPING=PASS 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET INTERNALPING=FAIL
ECHO.
ECHO Internal ping test %INTERNALPING%
```

The details for the hostname and terminal as set earlier in the script.
It's also important that the script not display the workings only show the echo lines and result. I have used

> /f >nul 2>&1

elsewhere in the script to suppress output

Comment: What do you mean with "result from C"? Result from `PING ...` executed in B?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes that's what I need. need to know if C responds or times out from the request sent by B.

Comment: My other thought on this was to use tokens to read the output of the ping and extract my result from that but I'm really unsure of the implementation or how I would get a single line ping result to work with via PSEXEC or similar.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Windows IT Pro](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec) (referred in [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)):

> PsExec displays the process's exit code and returns the exit code as
>   its own exit code.

So, your batch should work.

Put `ECHO ErrorLevel=%ERRORLEVEL%` after `PSEXEC ...` just to get sure.

To disable outputing, append `>NUL 2>NUL` or `>NUL 2>&1` to `PSEXEC ...` command-line. Without `/f` as you used (where did you get it???)

Comment: I'll give it another test tomorrow but I have tested this before posting with no joy. the errorlevel always comes back as 0 even when terminal C is offline. I assumed it was because the errorlevel was reflecting that the PSEXEC command itself had run on B

Comment: hmm, no luck. the ping result appears as reply from xx.xx.xx.xx destination host unreachable and errorlevel 0. obviously this would be a fail so errorlevels may not be the way to do this.